# how to work with directory in server go and client java grpc

Tags: android, go, grpc-java, grpc-go

I have a question before I had a springboot api for android with grpcs calls but as it had the same directory both the server and the client run normally now that I migrated the api to golang it stopped working with the following error message:

unimplemented unknown service com.example.categoryproductquery.src.CategoryProductQuery

```
My CategoryProductQuery.proto:

syntax = "proto3";
option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "com.example.categoryproductquery.grpc";
option go_package = "internal/infra/grpc/pb";

message starQueryRequest{
    int64 id=1;
}

message startQueryResponse{
    string star=1;
    int32 total=2;
}

message CategoryQueryRequest{
    string data=1;
    int32 pageNum = 2;
}

message CategoryQueryWithoutRequest{
    int32 pageNum = 2;
}

message CategoriesQueryRequest{
    string active=1;
}

message CategorySearchRequest{
    string title=1;
    int32 pageNum = 2;
}

message CategoryEntity{
    string category_id=1;
    string category_active = 2;
    string category_name=3;
    string category_slug=4;


}

message CategoriesResponse{
    repeated CategoryEntity categories=1;
}

message PhotoEntity{
    string photo_photo=1;
    string photo_type=2;
    string photo_title=3;
    string photo_active= 4;
}

message CategoryProductQueryRequest{
    string product_id=1;
    repeated CategoryEntity categories=2;
    string product_title=3;
    int64 product_quant=4;
    string product_slug=5;
    string product_active = 6;
    string product_description = 7;
    string product_price_un=8;
    string product_price_kg=9;
    int32 star=10;
    repeated PhotoEntity photos=11;
    string createdAt=12;
    string updateAt=13;

}

message CategoryQueryResponse{
    int32 count=1;
    int32 pages=2;
    string nextPage=3;
    string prevPage=4;
    repeated CategoryProductQueryRequest results=5;
}

message StarRatingRequest{
    string ip = 1;
    string product_id=2;
}

message StarRatingList{
    string star_rating_id=1;
    string product_id=2;
    string ip=3;
    int32 star=4;
    string createdAt=5;
    string updateAt=6;
}

message StarRatingRespose{
    repeated StarRatingList starrating=1;
}

message ProductSingle{
    string product_id=1;
}

service CategoryProductQuery {
    rpc getCategoryProduct(stream CategoryQueryRequest) returns (stream CategoryQueryResponse);
    rpc getCategoryProductWhithout(stream CategoryQueryWithoutRequest) returns (stream CategoryQueryResponse);
    rpc getCategoryProductSearch(stream CategorySearchRequest) returns (stream CategoryQueryResponse);
    rpc getCategories(CategoriesQueryRequest) returns (CategoriesResponse);
    rpc getStarProducts(starQueryRequest) returns (startQueryResponse);
    rpc getStar(StarRatingRequest) returns (StarRatingRespose);
    rpc getProductSingle(ProductSingle)returns(CategoryProductQueryRequest);
}
```

My categoryproduct_service.go:

```
package service

import (
    "context"
    "io"
    "math"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/rafaelsouzaribeiro/category-product-query/internal/infra/grpc/pb"
    "github.com/rafaelsouzaribeiro/category-product-query/internal/usecase"
)

type CategoryProductService struct {
    pb.UnimplementedCategoryProductQueryServer
    CategoryProductFind    usecase.CategoryProductFindUseCase
    CategoryProductFindAll usecase.CategoryProductFindAllUseCase
    Categories             usecase.CategoriesFindUseCase
}

func NewCategoryProductService(find usecase.CategoryProductFindUseCase,
    findall usecase.CategoryProductFindAllUseCase,
    categories usecase.CategoriesFindUseCase) *CategoryProductService {
    return &CategoryProductService{
        CategoryProductFind:    find,
        CategoryProductFindAll: findall,
        Categories:             categories,
    }
}

func (c *CategoryProductService) GetCategoryProduct(stream pb.CategoryProductQuery_GetCategoryProductServer) error {

    for {
        CategoryProduct, err := stream.Recv()

        /// se chegou no final
        if err == io.EOF {
            return nil
        }

        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        counts, err := c.CategoryProductFindAll.GetProductsAll(string(CategoryProduct.Data))

        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        pageSize := 10
        skip := 0
        pageNum := int(CategoryProduct.PageNum)

        if pageNum > 0 {
            skip = (pageNum * pageSize)
        }

        products, err := c.CategoryProductFind.FindCategoriesByCategoryID(string(CategoryProduct.Data), skip, pageSize)

        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        var allProducts []usecase.CategoryProductDto

        for _, product := range *products {
            allProducts = append(allProducts, product)

        }

        println(len(allProducts))
        totalPagina := int(math.Ceil(float64(counts.Count) / float64(pageSize)))

        next := 0
        if pageNum+1 >= totalPagina {
            next = 0
        } else {
            next = pageNum + 1
        }
        prev := 0
        if pageNum > 0 {
            prev = pageNum - 1
        }

        err = stream.Send(&pb.CategoryQueryResponse{
            Count:    int32(counts.Count),
            Pages:    int32(totalPagina),
            NextPage: strconv.Itoa(next),
            PrevPage: strconv.Itoa(prev),
            Results:  ConvertProducts(allProducts),
        })

        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
}

func (c *CategoryProductService) GetCategories(ctx context.Context, in *pb.CategoriesQueryRequest) (*pb.CategoriesResponse, error) {

    categories, err := c.Categories.GetCategories(in.Active)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    var pbCategories []*pb.CategoryEntity
    for _, category := range *categories {
        pbCategory := &pb.CategoryEntity{
            CategoryId:     category.CategoryID,
            CategoryName:   category.CategoryName,
            CategoryActive: category.CategoryActive,
            CategorySlug:   category.CategorySlug,
        }
        pbCategories = append(pbCategories, pbCategory)
    }

    return &pb.CategoriesResponse{
        Categories: pbCategories,
    }, nil
}

func ConvertProducts(allProducts []usecase.CategoryProductDto) []*pb.CategoryProductQueryRequest {
    var pbProducts []*pb.CategoryProductQueryRequest
    for _, product := range allProducts {

        var pbPhotos []*pb.PhotoEntity
        for _, photo := range product.Photos {
            pbPhotos = append(pbPhotos, &pb.PhotoEntity{
                PhotoPhoto:  photo.PhotoPhoto,
                PhotoType:   photo.PhotoType,
                PhotoTitle:  photo.PhotoTitle,
                PhotoActive: photo.PhotoActive,
            })
        }

        var pbCategories []*pb.CategoryEntity
        for _, category := range product.Categories {
            pbCategories = append(pbCategories, &pb.CategoryEntity{
                CategoryId:     category.CategoryID,
                CategoryName:   category.CategoryName,
                CategoryActive: category.CategoryActive,
            })
        }

        pbProducts = append(pbProducts, &pb.CategoryProductQueryRequest{
            ProductId:          product.ProductID,
            ProductTitle:       product.ProductTitle,
            ProductQuant:       product.ProductQuant,
            ProductSlug:        product.ProductSlug,
            ProductActive:      product.ProductActive,
            ProductDescription: product.ProductDescription,
            ProductPriceUn:     product.ProductPriceUn,
            ProductPriceKg:     product.ProductPriceKg,
            Star:               int32(product.Star),
            Photos:             pbPhotos,
            Categories:         pbCategories,
            CreatedAt:          product.CreatedAt.Format(("02/01/2006 15:04:05 ")),
            UpdateAt:           product.UpdateAt.Format(("02/01/2006 15:04:05 ")),
        })
    }

    return pbProducts
}
```

My ManagedChannel.tk:

```
package com.example.quitandagrpc.classes

import io.grpc.ManagedChannel
import io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder
import io.grpc.Metadata
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.asExecutor

class ManagedGrpc(private val token: String="") {
    private var port:Int =0
    private var host:String=""
    lateinit var canal:ManagedChannel

    fun inicializar(cond:String):Metadata {
        host="x.x.x.x"

        when(cond){
            "categoryproduct"->{
                port=30007
            }
            "user"->{
                port=30015
            }
            "usercommand"->{
                port=30004
            }
            "categoryproductcommand"->{
                port=31533
            }
            "cartpurchasequery"->{
                port=30010
            }
            "cartpurchascommand"->{
                port=30012
            }
        }

        canal = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port)
            .executor(Dispatchers.IO.asExecutor())
            .usePlaintext()
            .build()


        val header = Metadata()
        val key = Metadata.Key.of("Authorization", Metadata.ASCII_STRING_MARSHALLER)
        header.put(key, "Bearer $token")

        return header
    }

    fun closeChannel() {
        // Fecha o canal se estiver aberto
        canal.shutdownNow()

    }

    fun getChannel(): ManagedChannel? {
        return canal
    }


}
```

Does anyone know if I have to have the same directory for both the server and the client?

Thank you very much to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

I just created the CategoryProductQuery.proto with protoc again and put it on android and it worked maybe it's because it has the "go_package" now